# Getting a List<String> from XML using JAXB (Moxy)

Tags: xml, eclipselink, jaxb2, java-6, moxy

I am using jdk1.6 and eclipselink-2.3.2.v20111125-r10461

I have an XML similar to:

```
<alpha>
     <beta>
            <omega>abcd</omega>
            <gamma>
                <delta>001</delta>
                <delta>002</delta>
                <delta>003</delta>
            </gamma>
     </beta>
</alpha>
```

My annotated bean looks like:

```
@XmlRootElement(name = "alpha")
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
public Class Alpha {

    @XmlPath("beta/omega/text()")
    private String omegaValue;

    @XmlElement(name = "delta")
    @XmlElementWrapper(name = "gamma")
    private List<String> deltaList;

    public String getOmegaValue() {
        return omegaValue;
    }

    public void setOmegaValue(String omegaValue) {
        this.omegaValue = omegaValue;
    }

    public List<String> getDeltaList() {
        return deltaList;
    }

    public void setDeltaList (List<String> deltaList ) {
        this.deltaList = deltaList ;
    }
}
```

in my test code i do the following to check the list, but it is empty.

```
System.out.println(alphaInstance.getDeltaList().size());//returns 0!!
for (String deltaValue: alphaInstance.getDeltaList()) {//empty!!
    System.out.println(deltaValue);
}
```

Am doing something wrong out here? The omegaValue works fine. Please help, thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your mapping for the `deltaList` property is missing the beta level.  You could use the `@XmlPath` annotation and do the following:

```
@XmlPath("beta/gamma/delta/text()")
private List<String> deltaList;
```

**For More Information**

- http://blog.bdoughan.com/2010/07/xpath-based-mapping.html

Comment: you just got yourself a MOXy fan! :-)